# what is the difference between propaganda and hoax?

Tags: word-usage, politics, concept

I was looking for definitions of propaganda and hoax. The problem is that people in the internet are trying to post their own definitions without a clarification.

At the end I chose these following definitions:

**Propaganda:** is a fabricated story spread to manipulate readers and to harm the interest of a particular party.

**Hoax:** is similar to propaganda but the main aim of the author is not to manipulate readers' opinions but to convince them of the validity of a paranoia-fueled story.

Do you think that they are correct/clear?

Comment: No. A hoax is, in general, nothing like propaganda. **OED** - **Propaganda** 3. The systematic dissemination of information, esp. in a biased or misleading way, in order to promote a political cause or point of view. Also: information disseminated in this way; the means or media by which such ideas are disseminated. **Hoax** a. An act of hoaxing; a humorous or mischievous deception, usually taking the form of a fabrication of something fictitious or erroneous, told in such a manner as to impose upon the credulity of the victim.

Comment: I would disagree that a hoax is necessarily related to a paranoia-fuelled story. It would be possible to set up a hoax which sought to convince people of a positive event which had not happened and it would still be a hoax, for example a story that someone had invented a viable small-scale fusion reactor that worked at room temperature. Such a hoax could be the basis of an investment scam. Also propaganda is not necessarily completely untrue, some of the most effective propaganda is based on biased and/or exaggerated reporting of facts.